# Can Symfony2 render a twig from an unregistered bundle?

Tags: templates, symfony, bundle, twig

I tried specifying the twig explicitly with no success

"src/Folder/bundlename/Resources/views/folder/template.html.twig"

Unable to find template

and obviously the "Bundle:DownloadNowButtons:template.html.twig" isn't working either because the bundle is unregistered

Comment: looks like I can add to the path parameter http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/templating/namespaced_paths.html

Comment: You should add this as an answer and accept it if it solved your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I was able to solve this by following the documentation located here
http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/templating/namespaced_paths.html

Once I added the views folder of the unregistered bundle to the twig path param, I was able to render the view by calling @[name space]/[path from twig.path dir]